# HTML - Mixing UTF-8 coming from MySQL database and special chars into HTML

Tags: php, mysql, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database where everything is defined in `UTF-8` (charsets, collations, ...).
I have a PHP page that gets datas from that database and display it.
That PHP page contains some hard text with special charaters, like `é`, `à`, ...

My PHP page has meta charset defined to `utf-8`.
I call `mysql_set_charset("utf8");`
My PHP page is written on an editor that is configured to encode to `utf-8 Unicode` (Dreamweaver CS4, there is no other utf-8 option)

Anything coming from the database is ok, but...
I can't display well the hard special characters (é, à, ù, ...).
Same problem when I use `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($datafromdatabase));` on datas coming from database. Here it's really problematic.

**What may I do to keep using UTF-8, but being able to display well the special chars without having to use their html equivalent (`&eacute;, &agrave, ...`) ?**

**EDIT**
The problem with hard characters was coming from the php page that was not saved using adhoc encoding. I have created a new document copyed/pasted the old code into that new page, and saved it over the old page. No more problem with hard characters.

But I still have problems with  `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($datafromdatabase));`
using `$datafromdatabase = htmlentities(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($datafromdatabase)), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")` does not solve the problem. I have stange characters starting with # for each `é, à, ù` in the text coming from the database (stored as `&eacute, ...`)

Comment: So only characters in your PHP/HTML files do not come out right? Sounds like the file is not really saved as UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze : no, the strip_tags(html_entity_decode($datafromdatabase)); statement generates the same problem, but displayed characters are bad but different than thos from the HTML file.

Comment: So *all* your non-ASCII characters are screwed up? And why are you stripping tags and decode HTML entities for data from the database?

Comment: @deceze:to be able to keep the first real n characters without having to deal with &eacute styles-chars and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with hard characters was coming from the php page that was not saved using adhoc encoding. I have created a new document copyed/pasted the old code into that new page, and saved it over the old page. No more problem with hard characters.

For the problem coming from `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($datafromdatabase));` I had in fact to use `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($datafromdatabase, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 2):

I looks like it's a problem with your browser properly displaying the characters rather than saving.

Check two things.

Issue a utf8 http header

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
```

And make sure your html declaration is mentioning utf8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

That's for html 4

If your document is properly encoded, this should do it.